# Skip to the right section in the contact form

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

how can I make the page jump right to the chosen section of the main page (for reference: klient/#contact) after submitting a contact form?

```
def klient(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        form = ContactFormForClient()
    else:
        form = ContactFormForClient(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            messages.success(request, 'Form submission successful')
            company = form.cleaned_data['company']
            from_email = form.cleaned_data['from_email']
            phone = form.cleaned_data['phone']
            subject = form.cleaned_data['subject']
            message = form.cleaned_data['message']

            full_messege = """
            WIADOMOŚĆ OD KLIENTA

            Firma: %s
            Numer telefonu: %s
            Adres e-mail: %s
            Temat: %s
            Treść:

            %s
            """ % (company, phone, from_email, subject, message)

            try:
                send_mail(company, full_messege, from_email, ['bow.infos.kontakt@gmail.com'])
            except BadHeaderError:
                return HttpResponse('Invalid header found.')
            return render(request, 'client_pl.html')
    return render(request, "client_pl.html", {'form': form})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change this in the 2nd last line:

```
return render(request, 'client_pl.html')
```

to:

```
return redirect('klient/#contact')
```